# Computing the curvature tensor of a linear connection.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to find a simple formula for Reimannian and Ricci curvature of a linear connection, but I derive complicated formula. My problem is as follows

> A Reimannian manifold $(M^n , g)$ with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ is given. I want to compute the $\bar{R}$ curvature of the following linear connection $$\overline{\nabla}_X Y =\nabla_X Y + {1\over6}N(X,Y)+ {1\over6}N(Y,X)$$
> where, $N$ is a $(2,1)$-tensor field.
> Then, what will be the Ricci tensor
> $$\overline{Ric}(X,Y)=tr_g (Z\to \bar{R}(X,Z)(Y))$$?

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: The first time any of us calculates a formula like this, we get a big mess. Usually even after many tries. You just have to keep trying and, either just grind through it to the end or look for opportunities along the way to make the calculation simpler. You could also post whatever you've managed to do so far. The first thing I would do is to temporarily replace the last two terms by simply a symmetric (2,1) tensor $T$.

Comment: @Deane  Thank you very much for your wise answer.

Comment: As a further hint, this type of computation often simplifies immensely in normal coordinates.

Comment: @kajelad thanks for your nice hint.